# Front-end development in french?

Tags: html, css, frontend

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I just got a job developing a site in French.  Is there anything I should do or do differently that I wouldn't do if I were coding an English site?

Comment: You're not actually planning to code in French, right?

Comment: Watch for those darn accented letters. You better get your text-encoding straight. Also - think about the locale - numbers are written differently (decimal commas, so 2,000 is not two thousand but two point nothing), order of numbers in dates (today is 16-02 not 02-16...), ...

Comment: Just prefix every element with `le` eg `<lediv><leform>...` ;p

Comment: Thanks for your beaucoup wisdom, but no I'm not planning on coding in French, I meant more like declaring lang="fr" or anything else like that I may not be aware of.

Comment: You dont code in english ... there's PHP HTML and so on ..... and Thankfully they all use english alphabet.. what might happen if all syntaxes and functions change into chinese

Comment: That isn't what I mean, I know that.  I'm talking about localization in general and how it works.  I have no experience with it, so I figured I'd ask if there was something I have to do differently.  Sorry if that is stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few typographic specialties in French that a well-designed HTML page should handle somehow, such as special spacing rules around punctuation characters. They are somewhat tricky to handle with just HTML and CSS. See my page [HTML authoring in French](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/french.html).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have anything to worry about with regards design / look n feel.

You'll have a lot to worry about with regards content though.

- Date formatting
- Currency formats
- Thousand separator and other stuff

I'm assuming you aren't saddled with the task of working on the content as well.

Comment: Wow, imagine that, an actual answer :)  What about declaring it in the html tag?  Do I need to use "lang="fr"?

Comment: @Syren, declaring the language with `lang` attribute is good practice and recommended in different specs, but it does not have much impact at present. It helps assistive software, and it is essential if you add some hyphenation mechanism (with CSS or JavaScript).